# If my asp.net application spawns a process, does the process runs inside the same application domain in which the asp.net application runs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Based on my understanding:

1. IIS invokes a single worker process for the whole asp.net applications on the server.
2. The worker process contains a collection of application domains.
3. Each application domain in the worker process corresponds to an asp.net application.

If my asp.net application spawns a process for each request, does the process runs inside the same application domain in which the asp.net application runs?

```
    Process p = new Process();

    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);

    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-fmt=pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode " + inputpath;
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;

    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdftex.exe";

    p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to optimize an asp.net spawning a new process for each request ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242652/how-to-optimize-an-asp-net-spawning-a-new-process-for-each-request)

Comment: Asking the question again isn't going to change the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no. When you start a new process, a new process space is created and it is independent of your app domain. The spawned process may or may not be managed code and run as an independently process. It may inherit the security context of its creator if appropriate setting is defined.

Comment: In addition to inheriting its creator security context, does the spawned process have a possibility to take a security access level that is higher than the creator has?

Comment: Not by default, but you can try playing with setting username and password of ProcessStartInfo to impersonate the creator. Another option is try turning on UseShellExecute which will start the process using the OS shell.

Answer (score 1):

No. An AppDomain can't exceed the boundary of the process it is inside.
Furthermore, AppDomains are a concept from the .NET world. If `pdftex.exe` is a .NET application, it has its own AppDomain. If it isn't a .NET application, it doesn't have an AppDomain at all.