# Installshield 2010 fails to install

Tags: installshield, installshield-le, installshield-2010

I'm having problems installing InstallShield. ~ halfway in I get the following error messages and I can't seem to find any information on this. There are information about similar errors when deploying an own application but I do not find anything for the instalation om InstallShield.

The same error message (at least same info) appears if I try to install a free trial for Installshield 2014 from the company's website as well...

[image: Error message]

Thanks in advance for any aid.

Comment: Reboot and try the install again. You may be facing this bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308096

Comment: Wow a restart did the trick, I recently re-installed Windows 7 so it feels like I haven't done anything but restarting... But apparently one too few, if you write an answer I'll mark it as correct. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add the answer in case the link breaks at some point and to ensure the question is marked answered.

*When you try to install the .NET Framework, you receive an error 1935 (assembly install failure) error message if Mscoree.dll is in use before you start Setup.*

*This behavior occurs because Mscoree.dll is held in use for 10 minutes after you install (or remove) the assemblies. When you start another install, the installer tries to load its own version of Mscoree.dll to install the assemblies for the new program. Because another version of Mscoree.dll is already loaded, the failure occurs.*

Rebooting will release whatever lock is on mscoree.dll (Microsoft .NET Common Object Runtime Execution Engine - the engine that loads and executes assemblies containing Common Intermediate Language). For more information on this file read [the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605956/what-happens-when-a-net-application-is-started/6632609).