# JIT Compilation and Linking

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, jit, cil

May be a childish question, but I am really confused...

I understand that for NON JIT compilation, the linker embeds / injects (for static linking) the library codes into the object codes and generate the out file. But for JIT Compilation how does the linking happen (Particularly the static linking) ? Does JIT Compiler itself do the work of the linker (I mean look for the required library / symbols and inject them within the intermediate code before generating the final machine code)?

It would be good if If someone can answer this in flavor of C# and MSIL

Comment: I'm not sure that "static linking" is meaningful in a JIT compiler, but anyway, the whole question depends on how (and when) name resolution is done, which in turn will depend on the language's module system or equivalent. A comprehensive answer to such an open-ended question is probably an unreasonable expectation for a SO question. You should investigate (and, if necessary, ask about) a specific language, and maybe even a specific JIT compiler, after which you could investigate other ones for comparison.

Comment: Well @rici, let me update the question and lets talk about C# and MSIL

Comment: OK, retagged in the hopes of attracting someone who better understands those technologies. (That wouldn't be me.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605956/what-happens-when-a-net-application-is-started  So beautifully explained...