# Disable QuickEdit in Windows 10 cmd.exe

Tags: windows

I recently made the upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 10 on an important machine at an observatory (I should have done it long ago, I know...). I've noticed that in Windows 10, if I run a script on the windows command  line (cmd.exe) I can now interrupt the script from running by clicking on the terminal window.

When I click on the terminal the title bar changes and the word 'select' is prepended to the title. I have done this by accident several times now (when reorganising the open terminals) and caused a cascade of errors as an important running script has been interrupted and several things that depend on it have fallen ever.

The 'select' mode can be unselected by hitting return in the terminal, then the code that was interrupted continues to run as before.

I would like to disable this feature if possible. Has anyone encountered this? Thanks

Comment: For programmatically disabling QuickEdit Mode read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76855923/15016163

Answer (score 53):

Right click on the title bar, choose Properties, uncheck QuickEdit Mode, and click OK. If you want to disable it for all future command prompts too, do the same with Defaults instead of Properties.

[image]

Comment: Will this stop Quick Edit Node permanently?  I never ever want this, because of the select/freeze issue, and would like every cmd.exe to have this disabled.

Comment: Right click -> defaults -> uncheck quickedit mode to have all disabled for all cmd's.

Comment: Can you do it  with flags when starting new cmd from command line, e.g. `start cmd <some flags>` ??

Comment: @Empus no but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805712/492773) will help

Comment: @kichik yes, it helped! Also I was starting my own C# program as argument to cmd, and it turned out to be possible to disable it based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656846/how-to-programmatic-disable-c-sharp-console-applications-quick-edit-mode

Comment: Good addition to mention Defaults. This _may_ be a useful feature for some users, IDK, but what an asinine default setting!